# Gallery scrolling image jumps after moving 3/4 th of the screen

Tags: android, scroll, gallery

I am doing an app with gallery with showing a few images, when I scroll the images, they move and jump after a certain point. How do I make them smooth? Any sample code would be of great help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar problem. Looks like it can be caused by changes in layout, e.g. if you change text in textview which has wrap_content width. This cases layout change and probably forces gallery to update itself and it snaps right on current item.

I was able to fix it by playing with layout, setting fixed sizes where I could etc. but I don't know about permanent and reliable solution

EDIT: also I found this hack if above doesn't work for you

http://www.unwesen.de/2011/04/17/android-jittery-scrolling-gallery/

Comment: Thanks Lope, thats was kinda helpful but could you please help me on setting up the view size on layout, sample code would be of great help. Thanks again

Comment: it is different for each layout. What helps for one view doesn't help with other. It is all about hierarchy and I am no expert on that :) I fixed it using trial and error approach. You can start setting fixed sizes on height and width of some elements, either in dp or I think match_parent helped me in some cases as well

Comment: that gives me an idea on solving it, Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve this problem by overriding the onLayout() method in the Gallery parent and then ignoring any calls where the changed flag was not true.

```
public class MyGallery extends Gallery {

    public MyGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        if (changed) {
            super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the above Gallery extends solution to work fairly well. However it was still causing some jitter. By simply overriding the **onLayout** method and look for number of views on screen I ended up with a "smooth as silk" Gallery view.
Note that I use this for a full screen slideshow effect.

```
public class SmoothGallery extends Gallery {
    public SmoothGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        int viewsOnScreen = getLastVisiblePosition() - getFirstVisiblePosition();
        if(viewsOnScreen <= 0)
            super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    }
}
```